# How to validate a filled input field?

Tags: javascript, validation

To check a form input has been filled in should I use

```
fieldname.value==''
```

or

```
fieldname.value.length<1
```

or does it not matter? If it does matter, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it matters. I would use this instead

```
if (!fieldname.value.length)  {
    //it has no length (0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases useful solution is check if user provided text different than space, so:

```
if (fieldname.value.match(/\S/g) !== null) {
    // there is something more than spaces
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Just a detail, the simple inequality operator `!=` can be used insted of the strict inequality operator `!==`, since the `match` method never returns `undefined`.